# how can I create a zip on java without using outputStream? (I don't want to write files into the computer)

Tags: java, file, zip

I need to create a zip file on Java; I can use the `File file = new File` to create a file but how can I out it in a zip without using `OutputStream`?

The code will be running in a place where I can't write anything so the `OutputStream` approach will not work for me.

Comment: Where the heck is the zip file supposed to go? And please get rid of the `PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP ME!`. That has no business being in your question and only will serve to distract. Your question is important, but it is no more important than any other question on this site. To help expedite your getting help, provide more detail and ask a better question.

Comment: Basically, you cannot, you can, however wrap an `OutputStream` in a `ZipOutputStream` and send content across a `Socket`, for example...Remember, `OutputStream` is a concept of something that can be written to, where, will depend on the implementation...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Heaven...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: or the other direction.

Comment: If you can't write anything to disk, you cannot create a file. This smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242). What are you trying to accomplish by creating a ZIP file? What is the end goal?

Comment: @MattBall The question is lame and previous comments are right but I need to note that the concept of File does not require disk storage. You could create a file in memory and send it somewhere via a socket.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand your question.  Do you mean ... how can I create a zip file, without writing the individual files inside it to disk first?  In other words, you want the zip file to be on disk, but not a whole lot of little files first?  If that's not what you mean, then please try to clarify.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp sure, but given the question, do you think the OP understands the distinction? That's why kept it simple. I think it will be more constructive if we can understand the end goal.

Answer (score 2):

> I can use the `File file = new File` to create a file

That doesn't create a file. `new FileOutputStream(...)` creates a file. `new File(...)` just creates an object in memory.

> but how can I put it in a zip without using `OutputStream`?

You can't. You can however create it without using a *`FileOutputStream`,* if that's what you're really asking. Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and wrap a `ZipOutputStream` around it. Then when you've closed the `ZipOutputStream` you can get the bytes from the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, whatever you've going to do with that.

> The code will be running in a place where I can't write anything so the `OutputStream` approach will not work for me.

Again you're conflating `OutputStream` with `FileOutputStream`.